# Centered form with material design lite

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am looking for an easy to get a login form centered on the screen using Google's [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/) library.

I've been through a number of iterations and this is the best I've come up with:

```
<div class="mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--2-col-tablet">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell--4-col">

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell-12-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="username" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Username</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell-12-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="password" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--2-col-tablet">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way of achieving a centered form on all screen sizes?

The divs with `&nbsp;` feel really yucky!

Comment: The divs may seem yucky, but that is the current recommended way to handle push state. You also don't need the last one in this structure, it will be fine without it.

Comment: For people reading this question now and in the future: MDL is deprecated and you should be using MDC. It sucks, but it'll save you more pain in the future to drop MDL unless a swarm of people start supporting it. I'm using it via https://github.com/kradio3/react-mdc-web and it is working out decently so far. I can control anything I need to, and I was able to get up and running pretty easily. Here is an example of some centered content with MDC: https://codepen.io/SgtPooki/pen/ZJxooN

Comment: As grid docs says https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid
you can set a maximum grid width (max-width) and its content will be centered.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

How about using "mdl-layout-spacer": See [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmmLzN)

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">This div is centered</div>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer a css solution:
Add an extra class to the grid containing the column to be centered. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbyORy)

```
<div class="mdl-grid center-items">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">This div is centered</div>
</div>

.mdl-grid.center-items {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Both options play nice when resizing.

Comment: any example of a login screen in MDL?

Comment: This answer is huge.  `justify-content: center;` is pure gold.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 26):

You can use `'mdl-typography--text-center'` :

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-typography--text-center">
    My center div
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works also with `mld-card`.

Answer (score 16):

Why not using `mdl-cell--N-offset` class? As pointed on the Components -> Layout -> Grid -> Configuration options in https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid:

> ### mdl-cell--N-offset
>
> Adds N columns of whitespace before the cell

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
    <p>Centered content!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a great and simple solution becauses it uses the framework configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Just add these CSS rules:

```
.mdl-layout {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and then put your content in this container:

```
<div class="mdl-layout">
  <!-- Your Content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with Google's Material Design Lite library, but why not just make a "container" element wrapping the columns? Example:

CSS:

```
.customContainer {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="customContainer">
    ...
</div>
```

Then from there you can put the full width column as desired.

Comment: You can also simply apply the `max-width` to the `mdl-grid` element to achieve the same effect.